# Where does apple mention all the important heights of UI components?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

Tab bar, navigation bar, tab bar icons, heights of UI controls... I've been reading the Human Interface Guidelines now the whole day, but they rarely mention heights. Do I look in the wrong place? Is there any document from Apple that mentions them in one place?

Comment: They aren't specifically documented, because relying on these values is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variation of the question see: - [Is it important to design iPhone App layouts flexible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852881/is-it-important-to-design-iphone-app-layouts-flexible/853032#853032)

**Apple provide the sizes of controls in the UICatalog SDK example. see Constants.h.**

Opinion is divided as to whether you should generate your app sizes this way. Currently it is safe as there is no other device of a different size. I think we will get warning of other devices and size of screen to fix any required changes.

Tony

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure they don't tell you because they don't want you to hard-code anything.  They might change sizes in future versions of the OS. In fact, they've filed a patent on changing the size of UI click targets in response to motion (so, if you're walking, and therefore jiggling the device, list elements might increase in height to prevent a mis-click).

Your best bet is to query the items in question as you're adding your subview. Each of their views (navbar, tab bar, etc) has a frame, from which you can get its size and location.

Answer (score 0):

The Constants.h file of the UICatalog example has the following info:

```
// these are the various screen placement constants used across all the UIViewControllers

// padding for margins
#define kLeftMargin             20.0
#define kTopMargin              20.0
#define kRightMargin            20.0
#define kBottomMargin           20.0
#define kTweenMargin            10.0

// control dimensions
#define kStdButtonWidth         106.0
#define kStdButtonHeight        40.0
#define kSegmentedControlHeight 40.0
#define kPageControlHeight      20.0
#define kPageControlWidth       160.0
#define kSliderHeight           7.0
#define kSwitchButtonWidth      94.0
#define kSwitchButtonHeight     27.0
#define kTextFieldHeight        30.0
#define kSearchBarHeight        40.0
#define kLabelHeight            20.0
#define kProgressIndicatorSize  40.0
#define kToolbarHeight          40.0
#define kUIProgressBarWidth     160.0
#define kUIProgressBarHeight    24.0

// specific font metrics used in our text fields and text views
#define kFontName               @"Arial"
#define kTextFieldFontSize      18.0
#define kTextViewFontSize       18.0

// UITableView row heights
#define kUIRowHeight            50.0
#define kUIRowLabelHeight       22.0

// table view cell content offsets
#define kCellLeftOffset         8.0
#define kCellTopOffset          12.0
```